# How to find adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

[image]

where

[image]

From this question I concluded that L^T = L*.
But when I find the transpose and then adjoint of the matrix I get

[image]

as the adjoint L* of L. But it is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "where [second image]".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have incorrectly found the "transpose and then adjoint" of the matrix, under any reasonable interpretation of those words. It is difficult to know what you're doing wrong since it's not clear how you got that answer in the first place. Note that the answer to the question given is **not** a $2 \times 2$ matrix as you seem to believe; it is a formula for the function $L^*$. In this case, it happens to be a formula of the form $L^*(X) = BX$ for some matrix $B \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, though it is not generally true that linear maps over $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ are of this form.

As for the correct approach, note that the definition of the adjoint states that for all $X,Y$, we have
$$
\langle L(X),Y \rangle = \langle X, L^*(Y)\rangle.
$$
The usual way to answer this kind of question is as follows. Using the properties of trace, rearrange the expression $\langle AX,Y \rangle$ into an expression of the form $\langle X, ?\rangle$ (where $A = \pmatrix{-4&-6\\-1&-8}$ and ? does not depend on $X$). What ever you end up with as "$?$" gives you a formula for $L^*(Y)$.

Comment: I got L*(Y) = A^TY for all Y. So do I just find the transpose of A?

Comment: The transpose of $A$ is not the answer to the question being asked. The answer to your question is $L^*(Y) = A^TY$, which is to say
$$
L^*(Y) = \pmatrix{-4&-1\\-6&-8}Y.
$$

Comment: What am I supposed to put for Y though. Sorry, I'm just really lost

Comment: You're not supposed to put anything for $Y$, you're supposed to write it in the form $L^*(Y) = \cdots$ because you are writing a formula for the linear **function** $L^*$. As an analogy, if the question was "what is the function whose graph is the line through the points $(0,1)$ and $(1,3)$", we might answer the question $f(x) = 2x + 1$. The question "what am I supposed to put for $x$" doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Does that mean that L*(Y) = (-4 -1 -6 -8)Y which equals L*(a b c d)?

Comment: Writing 
$$
L^*(Y) = \pmatrix{-4 & -1\\-6 & -8}Y
$$
is the same thing as writing
$$
L^*\left( \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix}-4 & -1\\-6 & -8\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.
$$
if that doesn't answer your question, then I don't understand what you're asking.